# What is the pressure that dark energy exerts on stars and planets while increasing the distance between them?

Tags: forces, pressure, astrophysics, space-expansion, dark-energy

What is the pressure that dark energy exerts on stars and planets while increasing the distance between them? I can understand that the pressure should be at a volume scales lower than molecules because if this was not the case the animals and plants and complex compounds would be affected (and maybe squizzed) by that pressure. So it should be so structured to be able to affect particles smaller than molecules. So how strong is that pressure and should that pressure eventually act on small particles as fermions?

Comment: Why do you think dark energy increases the distance between stars and planets? The energy density of matter inside a galaxy is much larger then the cosmic average (hence also as the energy density of dark energy)... the expansion of the universe, driven by dark energy or not, has no effect on the structure of galaxies, they are bounded by the much stronger gravity between the individual stars.

Comment: @Koschi I think (maybe I am wrong) because gravity is like a sink and at the scale of a galaxy it defeats the creation of new space but at larger scale it does not affect the creation of space so much which then causes increasing of distances....

Answer (score 1):

Nobody knows the exact nature of dark energy.

Dark energy is thought to be a repulsive force (that acts opposite to gravitational force) that drives the universe’s expansion.

> if this was not the case the animals and plants and complex compounds would be affected (and maybe squizzed) by that pressure. So it should be so structured to be able to affect particles smaller than molecules. So how strong is that pressure and should that pressure eventually act on small particles as fermions?

The  forces that hold "animals, plants and other complex compounds" together or prevent them from being "squizzed" is not the same as dark energy forces. These are normal electromagnetic forces. And just as importantly, dark energy is not known to interact via any of the fundamental forces (besides gravity) which includes the electromagnetic force.

Comment: The question was about dark energy, not dark matter

Comment: yes I misread it. thanks for that. I've edited.

Answer (score 1):

Dark energy can be seen as equivalent to negatively curved spacetime. In such a spacetime particles move away from each other (instead of accelerating towards each other in positively curved spacetime as caused by normal matter/energy). On small scales, this negative curvature is negligible or even contra-acted on by the particles making up atoms or molecules.
Only when the negative curvature becomes big enough (which may be the case if all galaxies have moved far away from each other), this can get so strong to tear atoms or molecules apart. This negative curvature (dark energy) is clearly present because of the observed accelerated expansion of the universe. This expansion isn't caused by an expanding spacetime, though many times you can read this is the case. It is the galaxies moving away from each other in curved spacetime. The pressure works in the opposite direction as the pressure caused by normal matter/energy. There is nothing that pushes though, as there is nothing that pulls for normal gravity. It's the natural state of matter to move away from each other (in negatively curved spacetime).

Answer (score 0):

Dark energy does NOT increase the distance between stars or planets. It does NOT affect matter at the molecular or particle level. It does not even act on galaxies. All these objects are bound objects, and thus the tiny dark energy is over-compensated by far. Dark energy is only relevant in essentially empty space in between galaxy clusters, or the universe as a whole.